# Where can I find the repository that contains a required package?

Tags: chrome, sles, zypper

I'm new to Linux. Now I just get started with SLES 11 installed on my company computer.

I want to install google chrome, so I downloaded:  `64 bit .rpm (For Fedora/openSUSE)`, but there's an error during installation:

```
google-chrome-stable-43.0.2357.125-1.x86_64 requires libX11.so.6()(64bit), but this requirement cannot be provided
```

I know in linux, the normal way to install a software package, is directly use the repository manager, it's zypper on sles, to install and it will resolve all the dependencies for me.

So it seems the repository containing the required package is missing, where can I find the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [rpmfind](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libX11.so&submit=Search%20...&system=&arch=x86_64) to find what package you need:

And I see:

```
xorg-x11-libX11-devel-32bit-7.6-10.2.x86_64.html    Include Files and Libraries mandatory for Development.  OpenSuSE 11.4 for x86_64    
xorg-x11-libX11-devel-32bit-7.6-10.2.x86_64.rpm
```

I don't see `xorg-x11-devel-64bit...` but it might be there and rpm find just doesn't know about it. Clicking [on the link for the above text](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/opensuse/11.4/x86_64/xorg-x11-libX11-devel-32bit-7.6-10.2.x86_64.html) I see:

```
Files

/usr/lib/libX11-xcb.so
/usr/lib/libX11.so
```

However I think this libX11.so is 32-bit and chrome is asking for a 64-bit version. So if you have `/usr/lib/X11.so` then you probably need to download a 32-bit version.